# C - Managing many labels with goto-statements

Tags: c, label, goto

Have a nice day,

I have to develop a program with as much `goto`-statements and `labels` as possible.
So my question is, how could one manage this easily?

I would like to implement one `goto` per `if`/`else`/`while`.
Don't know how to manage this at a proper way...

Let's suppose having a code in following form in the main():

```
while (...)
{
  y = 4 + 3;
  y = ...;

  if (...)
  {
    x = x - 5;

    if (...)
    {
      // do something
    }
    else if (...)
    {
      if (...)
      {
        // do something
      }
    }
    else
    {
      i = 10 + x;

      if (...)
      {
        // do something
      }
      else
      {
        // do something
      }
    }
  }
 ...
}
...
return 0;
```

At the end I would like to have a code in the form of following form:

```
while (...)
{
  ...
  goto PRIMARY_IF;
  ...
}

PRIMARY_IF:
  ...
  ...
END_PRIMARY_IF:

...
```

What is the best way to convert this code in a proper one with using `labels` and `gotos` for each `if`/`else`/`while`?

Would be appreciate any kind of help!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know why you would do this in the first place. Your C code is compiled (usually) through assembley, which has no loops. Your `while` loops and `if` statements turn into conditional jumps, so try and do it like that?

Comment: In C, the usual goal is to use the *fewest* labels and `goto` statements, preferably none.

Comment: What's in `// do something`, because if it uses any local variables, then you cannot jump outside the loop's scope as you would not be able to use those variables. If you want as many gotos as you can, then save for the initialization, you can reorder all rows in each scope and make your program execute from bottom to up.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I use only global variables. @Quimby can you demonstrate your idea with a short example? I think you mentioned the point I don't get as far. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JohnM Sure, https://pastebin.com/NfXKXiZ4 .